# What is meaning of 'accuracy' and 'confidence' in Nominatim search results?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I have the search result for the string "12 street" from Nominatim in GeoJSON (Python geocoder library):

```
'geometry'  : {'coordinates': [-110.0121359, 53.2489107],
               'type': 'Point'},
'properties': {'accuracy': 0.225,
               'address': u'12 Street, Lloydminster, City of Lloydminster, Alberta, T9V 1V4, Canada',
               'city': u'Lloydminster',
               'confidence': 9,
               'country': u'Canada',
               ...
               } # Truncated for simplicity.
```

What do the the terms 'accuracy' and 'confidence' mean exactly, in terms of geocoding?

Answer (score 1):

The confidence relates to how certain we are that the result corresponds to the input. For example, if  you get a result for  "10 street" and for  "120 street", the confidence will be smaller than a result for  "12 street".

The accuracy relates to the returned location. If the data comes from GPS address point, it is very accurate. If it is extrapolated from a road segment min-max address, it is somewhat accurate. If it is extrapolated from the postal code is has a lower accuracy.